# Difference between Striim and CR8

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka, striim

Both Striim and CR8 used for realtime data integration between RDBMS and Kafka. I want to know what are
the difference between them and specific uses of each

Answer (score 1):

Without writing here a book about both of them, I'd say:

- CR8™ is a streams software intended to get data from core legacy systems to data lakes in real time. The product is not intended for bidirectional replication, but only when your scenario covers one direction. Use cases when your source RDBMS need to feed SQL and NoSQL data targets into a Hadoop ecosystem.

[image]

- Striim is a platform, not a product. It contains several products inside, each designed for specific use cases. They possess one product specifically designed to interact with Kafka.

[image]

If your use case covers only Kafka, as a way to interact in unidirectional replication, I would suggest Striim , their product integrates with Kafka using CDC and log based repliacion. Also, if your future idea is the Cloud, Striim is your choice.

If your use case covers more than Kafka, and you want more flexibility of your product, I would go for CR8. I had a friend in a company and they use it for feeding Hive from Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Both seem to offer Oracle to/from Kafka loading.

So does [debezium](/questions/tagged/debezium), though, so I would first try that